# IP to Nation cron job

Tags: cron, iptonation

Is it possible to get a cron job url in order to update the IP to nation database?

I could use the url used in the ajax call when updating the database manually. But it requires an active session.

Answer (score 1):

IP to Nation doesn't set an action (ACT), so I don't think there's a neat way of doing this.

In ExpressionEngine, actions are given a unique ID and you can load /index.php?ACT=1234 to execute the action's code. For modules that use ACT you can run cron jobs by curl'ing the URL.